# Full screen android layout with rows having the same height

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, rows

I try to do android layout like this:

```
+---------+
|   20%   |
+---------+
|   20%   |
+---------+
|   20%   |
+---------+
|   20%   |
+---------+
|   20%   |
+---------+
```

But I can't do that. I tried each code i found in Internet. It's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#93B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#93B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: RelativeLayout isn't good as a container for weighted components. Use a LinearLayout and the problem is solved. Also note that weightSum is **optional**

Comment: `layout_weight` only works inside of a `LinearLayout` parent, not `RelativeLayout`, not to mention you aren't using any `RelativeLayout` specific features.

Comment: I see thet the editor change example. I mean layout with 5 horizontal rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

        android:weightSum="5" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#93B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#93B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You had everything mostly correct by setting the height of each view to `0dp` and then setting the `layout_weight` to 1.  What you forgot is that `layout_weight` is only used for `LinearLayout`, so you needed to change your `RelativeLayout` for it to work.  Also note that `weight_sum` doesn't do much in this case since your total weight already equals 5.